# Accepted answer was not added to my reputation

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation

An answer that was accepted for this question [unable to use redux-devtools-extension with react-router-redux syncHistoryWithStore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37513205/unable-to-use-redux-devtools-extension-with-react-router-redux-synchistorywithst/37520343#37520343) was not added to my reputation. Also the author did not get his 2 points for accepting.

I checked stackoverflow.com/reputation and it shows the correct score of 1961 but only 1945 on stackoverflow. What can I do? I guess I need help of a moderator?

Comment: On the following page it says your answer was unaccepted, then accepted: http://stackoverflow.com/users/402420/larrydahooster?tab=reputation&sort=time

Comment: @Pluto, I guess it was _first_ accepted, then unaccepted. I've heard The System's checking for such oddities regularly and fixing 'em all.

Comment: The author of the question apparently [got his 2 rep](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Q98xj.png). But indeed [your history](http://i.stack.imgur.com/DVsgO.png) shows that the answer seemed accepted at the beginning (with no rep awarded), then unaccepted and accepted again. The events occurred in the same second *2016-05-31 03:03:47Z*.

Comment: If your rep is incorrect the system will probably sort things out in a few hours.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yeah, there was some race condition - the OP accepted, unaccepted then accepted in short succession, causing some of the votes to not register.

I ran a manual recalc, so things are as you'd expect.